# No me valida contra la base de datos de MYSQL en un login

Tags: php, mysql, login

me pueden ayudar con esto por favor: estoy intentado hacer un login y al momento de ingresar la clave y el usuario me deja pasar con cualquier dato, no me valida contra la tabla que le estoy enviando en la consulta. aclaró que al momento de insertar un registro desde el formulario lo hace sin problema

Conexión a base de datos

```
    <?php 

    function Conectarse ()
    {
    $Conexion=new MySQLi ("localhost","Futboldh","Clave123","futbol_time");
    if ($Conexion->connect_errno)
        echo "Problemas en la Conexion" .$Conexion->connect_error;
    else
        return $Conexion;
    }
?>
```

Código php login

```
<?php 

include("Conexion.php");

$objConexion = Conectarse ();

$usuario = $_POST ['usuarioS'];
$clave = $_POST ['passwordS'];

if (isset ($usuario)|| isset ($clave)){

    echo "No se pudo iniciar sesion";

}

else
{
    $iniciarsesion= "SELECT * FROM tbl_login_registro WHERE Correo_electronico = '$usuario' AND Contraseña = '$clave'";

    $resultinicios= $objConexion->query($iniciarsesion);
}
if ($resultinicios)
{
    header ("Location:iniciologin.html");
}

?>
```

Comment: Creo que el problema es en el  `if ` final en el cual intentas verificar si el resultado del query es válido o no. ¿Por qué? Porque en caso de que la información no sea correcta, si no me equivoco, arroja un array vacio, esto quiere decir, que incluso si el array se encuentra sin data, de igual manera el if va a ser true ya que la variable `$resultinicios` contiene un array vacio, te aconsejo que mejor lo compares con un  `if(!empty($resultinicios)){ //Si no se encuentra vacio el array, quiere decir que está devolviendo data del SELECT. }`

Comment: Hola Brayan le agregue el !empty al if y aun me lleva a la pagina que tengo en el header con cualquier dato que ponga.